# How to design 16:4 Mux/Demux switch

Tags: switches, multiplexer

I have 4 different inputs In0, In1, In2 & In3. Each input is 4-bit, so there are total of 16 inputs. There are two selector inputs S0 & S1. And there is a 4-Bit Out. i.e. depending on the state of the S0 & S1, for ex. "00", 4-Bit In0 will be assigned to 4-Bit Out. I need to do this using a Mux/Demux switch but i could not understand how Mux/Demux switch can be used. Any guide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you do the same for 4-1 mux (that is the same, but for 1-bit inputs/outputs)?

Comment: @EugeneSh. If I use 4x1 mux, then only one bit of the required 4 bit will be taken. I need the remaining three bits as well as they are connected to another decoder.

Comment: Again, can you implement it? If you can, you simply parallelize four of your implementations interconnecting the Select lines.

Comment: I am having difficulty in deriving the truth table, can you point to any references, I could not find any.

Comment: @Zzz `difficulty in deriving the truth table` ... do you understand how a MUX functions?

Comment: @jsotola writing the truth table of 4x1 mux is not difficult. Eugene Mentioned that I should parallel 4 of 4x1 mux's , but suppose, In0 is 1010, depending upon the state of S0 & S1, only one bit will be transferred to Out. Suppose Out(3) is set to 1 by In(0), what about Out(1), that has to be set to 1 as well by output of In2 mux.

Comment: In0 is handled by 4 MUXes, not just by one MUX ... you may be getting confused by the 4-bit data and the 1 of 4 selection ... if In0 was 5 bits wide, then you would need to parallel 5 MUXes, each one able to select 1 of 4 inputs

Comment: I would be extremely glad if you could draw a crude picture of schematic by hand and post it in the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical 4:1 muxes (there are many devices, with "4052" in their name) have two channels:

[image: 4052 mux]
<sup>[(source)](https://www.ti.com/product/CD4052B)</sup>

Use one channel for each bit, i.e., you need two chips.